# Rails accessing variable outside Devise controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I am trying to access a variable passed in when a user (using Devise) signs in or signs out.

So I have edited the Devise Sessions controller (`/controllers/devise/sessions_controller.rb`) to setup a variable when a user logs in / out:

```
def create
@signed_in_token = "something"
```

However I now want to access this variable in `/views/layouts/application.html.erb`. It doesn't seem to be showing up...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem there that this actions are use `redirect_to` method after call. You can use `flash` obejct to pass variable to next render.

```
def create
   flash[:you_variable] ="test"
```

And than you can access it in view

```
<%= flash[:you_variable] %>
```

Comment: or perhaps you want to store it in the session, or in the database for the user. Rails Flash is only available for the next request, and is then wiped out. Session will last for the entire session, but takes up space in cookies in rails default. The database, of course, lasts until you modify it.  But you do need to store it somewhere persistent.  It is good to understand the basics of how the web/HTTP works when developing Rails, perhaps read up on that. In-memory instance variables are only available for the current request.

Comment: The 'flash[:variable]' thing works @mixan946 for signing in thank you. However for some reason it does not working when wanting to do a similar thing for signing out? Any ideas?

Comment: please look at the logs and see how many redirects was done after sign out, if more than 1 the flash than expired than. You can try to store thus variable in session, as suggested by @jrochkind